the location of the Python Playwright source code where the browser is launched
This is a python playwright source code debug problem.
I set breakpoints for debugging, but I can't trace the line of code where the browser is launched.
Here's the final position in the code where, after running it, the browser starts.

I suspect it establishes a local websockt server, sending a message to this server to launch the Chrome browser, but I can't locate where this code is.

Please see Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?. Why do you need to know where in the source code the browser is launched?

Revisiting this, it's important to pick a specific version of Playwright Python, since the source code will change from version to version. Motivation/actual problem being faced here is still unclear.
